# Assertion when declaring required arguments with argparse and 'nargs=*' arguments

Tags: python, argparse, assertions

Here is the current code to parse the arguments :

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a', '--action', required=True, metavar='', nargs=1, help='{block|release|clear|show|show_extended|}')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--interface', required=True, metavar='', nargs=1, help='interface name')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help='debug prints')
parser.add_argument('--ips', metavar='ips', nargs='*', help='ip addresses to block')
parser.add_argument('--handles', metavar='handles', nargs='*', help='filters handles to delete (usually 800::xxx), run with [show] to see')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

when I try to execute it without typing -a or -i, I get an assertion :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./block_traffic.py", line 112, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1690, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1722, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1946, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('argument %s is required') % name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2362, in error
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2324, in print_usage
    self._print_message(self.format_usage(), file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2280, in format_usage
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 281, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 211, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 332, in _format_usage
    assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
AssertionError
```

I noticed the assertion exception is gone as I remove the `nargs='*'` argument (one of the two)

What I want is for the first 2 arguments to be mandatory, the last 2 to be optional (with undetermined number of arguments) and `-d` to be optional flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argparse` does not like `metavar=''`.

Either give them a name or remove the options - but don't leave them as empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Without '-a' or '-i' it raises an error, because you made them 'required'.

But while formatting the 'usage' part of the error message:

```
usage: PROG [-h] -a act -i INTERFACE [-d] [--ips [ips [ips ...]]]
            [--handles [handles [handles ...]]]
```

it encountered an error while wrapping that long usage to 2 lines.  As noted by `gus42` that was produced by the 2 `metavar=''` parameters.  This is a known bug in the usage formatting.  `metavar` with `[]` also produces this problem.

The usage above uses `metavar='act'` in the first case, and default `None` in the second.  So you can shorten the `metavar`, but you can't suppress it entirely, at least not when the usage line is long enough to wrap.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware I stated `-a` & `-i` as required, the problem was an exception was raised and not a simple 'required arguments not provided'.  Changing the `metvar` to non-empty str, fixed the issue.